# Why is my angular service value not updating my scope?

Tags: angularjs

I have [this simple jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sonicblis/2f4bN/2/) that demonstrates what I thought would be a dynamic service value that could be monitored by any controller into which it was injected.  Here is the angular code:

```
var app = angular.module("application", []);

app.service("valueSetter", function(){
    that = this;
    this.serviceValue = {count: 1};
    this.updatevalue = function(){
        that.serviceValue.count = that.serviceValue.count + 1;
        console.log(that.serviceValue);
    };
});

app.controller("appcontroller", function($scope, valueSetter){
    $scope.scopeValue = valueSetter.serviceValue.count; 
    $scope.update = function(){
        valueSetter.updatevalue();
    };
});
```

and the html is simple:

```
<div ng-app="application" ng-controller="appcontroller">    
    Scope value is: {{scopeValue}}<br /><br />
    <input type="button" value="update" ng-click="update()" />
</div>
```

If you watch the console, you can see the service value increment, but the incremented value is not reflected in the controller scope.  Am I misunderstanding how this should be working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't bind to a service variable like that, but you can bind to a service function.  Add a getter to your service:

```
this.getValue = function(){
    return that.serviceValue;
}
```

Assign `scopeValue` in the controller to the getter:

```
$scope.scopeValue = valueSetter.getValue;
```

Bind like this:

```
Scope value is: {{scopeValue()}}
```

### Edit

You can also assign your `valueSetter` service to a `$scope` variable in the controller:

```
$scope.valueSetter = valueSetter;
```

And bind like this:

```
Service value is: {{valueSetter.serviceValue}}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jerrade/98zMH/)

### Edit 2

You can also change `this.serviceValue` in the service to be an object, like this:

```
this.serviceValue = {value: 1};
this.updatevalue = function(){
    that.serviceValue.value = that.serviceValue.value + 1;
    console.log(that.serviceValue.value);
};
```

In your controller, assign `scopeValue` like this:

```
$scope.scopeValue = valueSetter.serviceValue;
```

And then bind like this:

```
Scope value is: {{scopeValue.value}}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jerrade/rXXL8/1/)

The point is that if the property in the service is a primitive (essentially a string, number, or boolean), when you assign it to a scope variable, you're just making a copy of the value, and it has no link back to the service.  If the service property is an object, then when you assign it to a scope variable, you're copying the *reference* to the service property, which gives you the binding you are looking for.